# How to remove bottom color icons and labels from pie chart

Tags: ios, swift, charts, pie-chart

This is Pie Chart from Charts library. https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts

I was able to disable bottom labels using this line.

`chartView.usePercentValuesEnabled = false`

I also want to remove the square color icons and wasn't able to do so.

How do I remove the bottom color square icons from the pie chart?

[Pie Chart Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bGeLM.png)

Answer (score 6):

You can disable them using this command

```
     var chartView = PieChartView()
    chartView.legend.enabled = false
```